# Lua config file osm2pgsql issues with tagging nodes as part of relations and calculating length on demand

Tags: lua, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I am having trouble with the lua config file to add certain values to specific rows by ID on import.

I want to add relation info to nodes like is possible with ways, and I want to only compute length via way:transform(srid):length() for ways that belong to the relations I am interested in (subway, tram, and bus route relations) to speed up computation/import speeds.

In order to add relation info to nodes, I attempted to add the following:

```
local n2r = {}

function osm2pgsql.process_node(object)
    --local geom = object:as_point()
    if not (object.tags.amenity or object.tags.shop or object.tags.public_transport) then
        return
    end
    local row = {
        tags = object.tags,
        geom = object:as_point()
    }
    local g = n2r[object.id]
    if g then
        local refs = {}
        local ids = {}
        for rel_id, rel_ref in pairs(g) do
            refs[#refs + 1] = rel_ref
            ids[#ids + 1] = rel_id
        end
        table.sort(refs)
        table.sort(ids)
        row.rel_refs = table.concat(refs, ',')
        row.rel_ids = '{' .. table.concat(ids, ',') .. '}'
    end
    tables.nodes:insert({
        tags = object.tags,
        geom = object:as_point()
    })
end

function osm2pgsql.process_relation(object)
    local relation_type = object:grab_tag('type')
    if clean_tags(object.tags) then
        return
    end
    if relation_type == 'route' and (object.tags.route == 'subway' or object.tags.route == 'tram' or object.tags.route == 'bus') then
        tables.routes:insert({
            tags = object.tags,
        })
        for _, member in ipairs(object.members) do
            if member.type == 'w' then
                if not w2r[member.ref] then
                    w2r[member.ref] = {}
                end
                w2r[member.ref][object.id] = object.tags.ref
            --elseif member.type == 'n' then
            --    if not n2r[member.ref] then
            --        n2r[member.ref] = {}
            --    end
            --    n2r[member.ref][object.id] = object.tags.ref
            end
        end
    end
end
```

But due to the fact that lua doesnt have the built in function way_member_ids for node members, I don't know exactly how to make it work if its even possible. Maybe I just have to add the node ids to a json value as an array or something.

Additionally, I'd like to increase the processing speed from the current 2hrs by only calculating the length of a way if it matches the reprocess flag from a relation I am interested in. To do this I attempted to add the row value upon reprocessing by:

```
function osm2pgsql.process_way(object)
    if not (object.tags.railway or object.tags.highway) then
        return
    end
    if clean_tags(object.tags) then
        return
    end
    local geom = object:as_linestring()
    local row = {
        tags = object.tags,
        geom = geom,
    }
    local d = w2r[object.id]
    if d then
        local refs = {}
        local ids = {}
        for rel_id, rel_ref in pairs(d) do
            refs[#refs + 1] = rel_ref
            ids[#ids + 1] = rel_id
        end
        table.sort(refs)
        table.sort(ids)
        row.rel_refs = table.concat(refs, ',')
        row.rel_ids = '{' .. table.concat(ids, ',') .. '}'
        row.dist = row.geom:transfrom(srid):length()
    end
    tables.ways:insert(row)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For part 1 tagging nodes as members of relations: by looking at documentation again, seems impossible as docs quote

> "(It is currently not possible to mark nodes or relations. This might
> or might not be added in future versions of osm2pgsql.)"

that was missed initially.

For part 2 only getting geom length for relation members:
you can change the row.dist aspect to use table.concat like the row.rel_refs and row.rel_ids and this works